# React Hooks: How to update a nested array property in a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have a state of arrays. The array has an array nested inside it. This is what my state looks like:

```
const [record, setRecord] = useState([
    {
        name: "Pink Floyd",
        rank: 1,
        songs: [
            {
                name: "A",
                year: "1970",
                downloads: "10",
            },
            {
                name: "B",
                year: "1980",
                downloads: "20",
            },
            {
                name: "C",
                year: "1990",
                downloads: "5",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: "Led Zeppelin",
        rank: 2,
        songs: [
            {
                name: "D",
                year: "1965",
                downloads: "25",
            },
            {
                name: "E",
                year: "1975",
                downloads: "65",
            },
            {
                name: "F",
                year: "1985",
                downloads: "90",
            },
        ],
    },
]);
```

I am able to update the rank property by doing this :

```
setRecord(prevRecord =>
    prevRecord.map((el) =>
        el.name == "someName" ? { ...el, rank: "someRank" } : el
    )
);
```

Now, I want to update the 'downloads' property which is nested inside songs. How can I update the downloads property?

Comment: `{ ...el, rank: "someRank" , songs: el.songs.map(song => ({ ...song, downloads: 10 }))}`

Comment: @Konrad Thank You! setRecord((prevRecord) =>
 prevRecord.map(
  (el) =>
   (el.name = "bandName"
    ? {
      ...el,
      songs: el.songs.map((song) =>
       song.name == "songName"
        ? {
          ...song,
          downloads: "count",
          }
        : song
      ),
      }
    : el)
 )
);

Answer (score 0):

you must iterate through your state and look for item you want to change

```
  const newState = record.map((item) => {
    if (item.name === 'YOUR_DESIRE_NAME_TO_MODIFY') {
      const newSongs = item.songs.map((song) => {
        if (song.name === 'DESIRE_SONG_NAME_TO_MODIFY') {
          song.downloads = '100'
        }
        return song
      })
      item.songs = newSongs
    }
    return item
  })

  setRecord(newState)
```